# update and rendered tags in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to display/not display a primefaces datatable using the update tag in primefaces.

The table will render correctly when I reload (F5) the page but then I will lose all the data I had imputed into the form.  I was looking around for an ajax solution but I have been unable to find any so far.

My code:

```
<h:form id="adminForm">
  <h:selectOneMenu id="adminTypeMenu" value="#{adminBean.orgType}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="- Select One -"/>
    <p:ajax actionListener="#{adminBean.updateOrgType}" update="adminForm" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
  <p:dataTable id="adminMacTable" value="#{adminBean.currentArray}" var="currentOrg" 
    rendered="#{adminBean.Type eq 'bco'}" selection="#{adminBean.selectedMac}"
    emptyMessage="No Records Found">
    ...
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

The Currently implementation displays the dataTable but erases any form inputs I had.  Is there a way to render the datatable without clearing out my form values?

Update: Just tried the same code without  and used  but got the same result, still trying other methods!

Comment: What scope is your adminBean in?

Comment: The `#{adminBean.Type}` is invalid. Shouldn't it be `#{adminBean.type}`? Did you try `update="adminMacTable"`?

Comment: sorry I had modified some of the code when I pasted it over, thanks for the catch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <h:form id="adminForm" prependId="false">
  <h:selectOneMenu id="adminTypeMenu" value="#{adminBean.orgType}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="- Select One -"/>
    <p:ajax actionListener="#{adminBean.updateOrgType}" update="adminMacOutput" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
  <p:outputPanel id="adminMacOutput">
  <p:dataTable id="adminMacTable" value="#{adminBean.currentArray}" var="currentOrg" 
    rendered="#{adminBean.Type eq 'bco'}" selection="#{adminBean.selectedMac}"
    emptyMessage="No Records Found">
    ...
  </p:dataTable>
  </p:outputPanel>
 </h:form>
```

If that doesn't work, try putting the datatable inside a separate form and update this second form.

Comment: p:outputPanel was the correct solution!  I had actually used it before but had forgot about how useful it was :).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that AdminBean might be in request scope in which case your ajax event will update it but then it gets recreated when you press F5. If so then ViewScoped will help:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "adminBean")
@ViewScoped
public class AdminBean {

}
```

Comment: Currently the implementation is conversation scoped, I just tried the same thing again but with a p:panel instead of a form.  Same behavior unfortunately :(